# When I try to de-activate any plugin it gives error "Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]"

Tags: plugins, customization

When I try to de-activate any plugin it gives error. How to solve this? Plugin is getting de-activated but on clicking button "Deactivate" I get this error.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'youtuber_uninstall'  was given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 395**

Comment: Are you deactivating the same plugin multiple times? Or does that message comes on every plugin deactivation of multiple plugins?

Comment: @hakre - on every plugin

Answer (score 2):

The [Youtuber plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtuber/) has a little error: it has a function to remove it's own options, called [`wp_youtuber_uninstall`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/youtuber/tags/1.5.6/youtuber.php#L268). However, [it hooks into the `deactivate_plugin` option with the function `youtuber_uninstall`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/youtuber/tags/1.5.6/youtuber.php#L31), which does not exist. This [has been reported in the WP support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-youtuber-bugs-found-installuninstall).

You can remove the line that says `add_action('deactivate_plugin', 'youtuber_uninstall' );` to get rid of this error. In fact, be happy that it doesn't work, because the `wp_youtuber_uninstall` function should check *which* plugin is being uninstalled right now, and only clean up when it is remove itself. Right now, it would remove its own options every time *any* plugin is uninstalled.

Comment: I wanted to report this, but I'm missing the component:  http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/newticket

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess because I don't know the youtuber plugin well, but it does not uninstall correctly. I remember a similar problem we had with the Breadcrumb NavXT Uninstall routine and a similar error (the function-name was naturally different). I could handle that for MU setups that time by providing a uninstall.php with the plugin. It must be still in.

Please check that you have properly deactivated the youtuber plugin and the uninstall of it at least one-time was requested. After that, check if the plugin is still in the plugin directory. If so, rename the folder of the youtuber plugin. This should solve your issue.

You can delete the directory as well if you don't need it any longer, renaming often is faster and easier for testing. As always: Backup first.

Comment: @harke - but i'm using "youtuber plugin" and i need it and it's working fine. but i got this error when i try to disable any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with a plugin - try deactivating all of them and re-activating them one by one

Answer (score 0):

It's likely another plugin causing this, but just to be sure there are no theme functions messing with you, try temporarily switching to the default theme (twentyten or kubrick) and see if it persists. That's one big variable you can eliminate pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP access, go to wp-content/plugins

delete the folder having the name of the plugin and you are done